# Return a boolean DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I would like to create a DataFrame with booleans where np.nan == False and any positive real value == True.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,np.nan],'b':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan]})

DF.apply(bool) # Does not work
DF.where(DF.isnull() == False) # Does not work
DF[DF.isnull() == False] # Does not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, but it looks like `- np.isnan(df)` outperforms `pd.notnull(df)` by a landslide:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,np.nan],'b':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan]})


In [4]: - np.isnan(df)
Out[4]: 
       a      b
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3   True   True
4  False  False

In [5]: %timeit - np.isnan(df)
10000 loops, best of 3: 159 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit pd.notnull(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a convenience function for not [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html), called [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
In [11]: pd.notnull(df)
Out[11]: 
       a      b
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3   True   True
4  False  False
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the `notnull`. However, it seems that `- np.isnan(df)` is about 8 times faster :S

Comment: @root interesting! I suspect this is partially/mainly because `notnull` supports more `dtypes` than `float`?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing notnull() and isnan() on a df with some malformatting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,np.nan],'b':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan],'c':['fish','bear','cat','dog',np.nan]})

%%timeit
legit_dexes =  np.isnan(df[df<=""].astype(float)) == False
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 632 us per loop

```
%%timeit
legit_dexes = pd.notnull(df)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 751 us per loop

This variation that ignores malformed columns is also similar:

```
%%timeit
legit_dexes = np.isnan(df[df.columns[df.apply(lambda x: not np.any(x.values>=""))]]) == False
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 681 us per loop